# Zero papers in first PhD year. Is this common?

Tags: phd, career-path

I am terminating in these days the first year of my PhD in computer science. As I come from a different field, I spent the first semester doing courses, and most of the second in posing the basis of the thesis project: we have a couple of results, still nothing actually published, and only one paper waiting for approval (with a very low probability of being accepted ).

At the same time I can see many colleagues who already have published a couple of papers during the first year, so I am a bit worried. Am I going too slow? How common is for a PhD student to publish zero papers in the first year?

Also consider that the length of my PhD is 3 years, and this further worries me..

Comment: Which country are you in? Did you come in with a Master's?

Comment: Spain, and yes, but in a different field (math).

Comment: Ask your advisor if you should be worried. He/she can give you *much* better advice specific to your situation than we can.

Comment: I asked, and he says no, as the basis seems good for the next year. I wanted to know if this is common outside my group, in general..

Comment: UK, military history: quite normal to publish no papers at all while working on the PhD. So there is a very wide spread of possibilities. Your question may in fact be less to do with the requirements of the PhD itself, and more to do with wanting to build a "well-rounded" CV for future employment.

Comment: it is normal in cs theory in particular to spend the 1st year basically bringing yourself to the level for doing real research.

Comment: In my 3 year PhD I did not have any publishable results until my second year.  Some areas of research are relatively new, and therefore it may be able to publish new results quickly.  This may be why some of your colleagues published so quickly. In my case, I engaged in an area that had been around for over 100 years, while some other students studied Graph Theory, which has only been around for about half as long.

Comment: There's also a personality aspect to it. Some people are slower to get things started, but once they do, they're on a roll.

Comment: Don not worry about this, try approaching different problems.

Comment: My advice would be to talk with the adviser and to set milestones. Something like: get the submitted paper accepted and submit another one in the second year, publish two more in the third year. Also talk about the grade of the thesis and how much time and effort would need to go in there.

Comment: Not a complete answer, but just a quick input from a fellow PhD student in CS in USA. Here, it's normal as phds usually take about 4-5 years. In the first 1-1.5 years, courses and qualification exams take the most time for most of the students. So, it's normal according to my experience.

Answer (score 10):

In my experience (in environmental science), it is unusual for students to publish in their first year, and typically only happens if they are publishing work that was largely done before starting their PhD (e.g. from a research Masters degree).

Answer (score 4):

The number of papers published in the first year by a PhD student depends on the research area, country, university, the student and the supervisor. Comparing with other students in your department can give you some rough idea about their progress. However, you cannot always compare easily. For example, a student who is pursuing a PhD in the same topic as his master degree may be able to produce paper more quickly than a student who is starting a completely new topic and need to learn everything. To know about how well your pace is, the best is to ask your supervisor about it. By the way, the number of papers it not what matter the most. The important is to publish some quality papers in good conferences and journals by the end of your PhD. Some prefer to rush in publishing many papers, while other spend more time to write better papers. In my personal experience in CS, it is not uncommon that students will be busy during the first year with coursework and getting to know the research area so they may not publish much.

Comment: I am wondering where the downvote came from.

Comment: @scaaahu: Me too, and now there are two downvotes.